# Fluently map a collection of components

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object which contains a **list of value objects** but can't find a solution how to fluently map this. I have a value object mapped as `ComponentMap` (**no inline mapping**) like such:

```
public class ServiceSpecificationMapping : ComponentMap<ServiceSpecification>
{
    public ServiceSpecificationMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.PurposeOfService).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Description).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Price).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

The containing class has a definition like this:

```
public class ServiceContract : EntityBase
{
    ....
    public virtual List<ServiceSpecification> ServiceSpecifications { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

I have difficulties to code the correct mapping. I am looking for something like:

```
HasMany<ServiceSpecification>(x => x.ServiceSpecifications)
            .Table("tblServiceSpecification")
            .Component(<WHAT IS THE CORRECT LAMBDA HERE??>);
```

I need to reference the `ServiceSpecification` instance but I cannot find the correct syntax for that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <WHAT IS THE CORRECT LAMBDA HERE??> :) was asking exactly that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HasMany<ServiceSpecification>(x => x.ServiceSpecifications)
            .Table("tblServiceSpecification")
            .Component(m => {
                m.Map(x => x.PurposeOfService).Not.Nullable();
                m.Map(x => x.Description).Nullable();
                m.Map(x => x.Price).Not.Nullable();
            });
```

Comment: this works fine. But for me on flush or commit it deleted and reinserted the component instances. It turned out that my component class has to implement quality members - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158833/379279)

Comment: Yes this is always the case with components in NH, but is often overlooked. Thanks for pointing this out @xhafan.